# screenshot program for tablayout not happening for 4th and higher tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The following code is used to capture the layout and save it. This code works perfectly if have tabs count less than 3. If i have tabs count more than 3 then for first 3 it works but for later ones the value of View s is null. The variable currentposition will have the tab number. For example if i am looking at 8th Tab, then currentposition value will be 7.

```
View s = viewPager.getChildAt(currentposition);
if( s == null) return false;
s.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
Drawable drawable = getWindow().getDecorView().getBackground();
Bitmap primaryMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
s.layout(0, 0, s.getMeasuredWidth(), s.getMeasuredHeight());
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
Canvas cvas = new Canvas(primaryMap);
drawable.draw(cvas);
File shareFile = saveImages(primaryMap);
```

my tablayout.xml looks as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        style="@style/MyTabLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp20"
        android:background="@color/ORANGE"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        android:id="@+id/tab_options" />

    <!-- <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager !-->
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

also interesting to see that viewPager.getChildCount gives only 2 even though there are more than 10 tabs. The code for adding tab is given below

```
TabLayout tab =  findViewById(R.id.tab_panchanga);
tab.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tab.setTabTextColors(Color.BLACK,Color.WHITE);
tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("1st Tab"));
tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("2nd Tab"));
tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("3rd Tab"));
tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("4th Tab"));
tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("5th Tab"));
tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("6th Tab"));
ViewPager viewPager =  findViewById(R.id.pager);
Pager p = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(),tab.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(p);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab));
```

am i missing something here ?

Comment: This issue seems like of page loaded in viewpager. Try to capture the page on which you actually are.

Comment: i am doing the same through currentpage, because currentpage is the one which is loaded on viewpager

Comment: what does this line states `if i am looking at 8th Tab, then currentposition value will be 7.`?

Comment: which means that each page is numbered 0 to n, so when i am on page 8 of tab the value in variable current position will be 7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got resolved. I save the fragment view of every tab. This way i can save entire layout.